# How to select results from a MySQL DB using Strpos instead of a While statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been using the PHP function strpos to find results containing the characters of a string from a DB:

```
User Types: Hel
Results: Hello, Hell, Helli, Hella
```

I have it basically query the entire table:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events");
```

And then ran a while statement to see which of the results contain the characters of the input:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {

    $pos = strpos($row['Title'], $q);
        if ($pos === false) {
        } else {
            echo $row['Title'];
        }
  }
```

And to find the number of results, I was using:

```
$n = $n++
```

Inside of the while statement.

**I know you can use:**

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

**To find the number of results if you are only selecting those values from the database, but do I have to use this while statement to find the number of results that match the strpos function? Or can I put the strpos in to the Select From query?**

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Taylor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems highly inefficient.  Why wouldn't you simply let the database do the searching for you?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events WHERE Title LIKE '" . addslashes($q) . "%'");
```

Then just loop through the results.

Comment: Thank you. I feel stupid for doing it the way I did above. I was wondering though, what is the addslashes() for?

Comment: It escapes quotes in the supplied string.  Never trust the end-user.  You want to make sure they don't mess with your database doing stuff they shouldn't.  If you didn't have addslashes() the user could input `'; DROP TABLE Events;` and get rid of your whole table.  This will make sure their quotes get escaped so they can't run anything you didn't intend.

Answer (score 2):

You could update your SQL to something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Events
WHERE Title LIKE '{your_string}%'
```

Make sure to filter for sql injection though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Events WHERE field1 LIKE '%something%'
```

Where the special `%` characters say "Anything of any length"; so we're searching for something (or nothing), then the string, then something (or nothing.) For example, searching for `%f%` will match `foo`, `off`, and `affirmative`.

Just as general advice, I recommend that you use php's [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) class; it's an improved version (hence the `i`), and provides prepared statements, so you won't have to worry too much about SQL injections.